# Открытие книги Excel

Tags: c#, excel, процесс

Пользователь указывает название желаемой для открытия книги в приложении (Excel Add-in уровня документа), но есть варианты - книга может быть уже открыта в том же процессе, может быть открыта во втором процессе, а может быть открыто 3 и более процессов Excel, также книга может быть еще не открыта.

Для варианта в том же процессе подходит

`wbTarget = this.Application.Workbooks[Название];`

Для варианта в другом процессе подходит

```
Excel.Application xl = (Excel.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
wbTarget = xl.Workbooks[Название];
```

Для варианта, когда книга не открыта, подходит

```
wbTarget = this.Application.Workbooks.Open(Название, ...);
```

А вот когда процессов Excel 3 и более, уже нет определенности, какой процесс вернет Marshal. Как можно пройтись по всем процессам Excel для поиска книги по названию?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel открывает один объект приложений во время старта. Открытие или создание последующих excel-файлов не регистрирует ещё один объект в системе. Именно поэтому и появляется произвольность в выборе текущего объекта.
Вот такой код нашелся на просторах интернета. Он позволяет пройтись по всем открытым инстансам экселя:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

class Program
{
    [DllImport("Oleacc.dll")]
    public static extern int AccessibleObjectFromWindow(
          int hwnd, uint dwObjectID, byte[] riid,
          ref Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Window ptr);

    public delegate bool EnumChildCallback(int hwnd, ref int lParam);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern bool EnumChildWindows(
          int hWndParent, EnumChildCallback lpEnumFunc,
          ref int lParam);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetClassName(
          int hWnd, StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);

    public static bool EnumChildProc(int hwndChild, ref int lParam)
    {
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(128);
        GetClassName(hwndChild, buf, 128);
        if (buf.ToString() == "EXCEL7")
        {
            lParam = hwndChild;
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
        EnumChildCallback cb;
        List<Process> procs = new List<Process>();
        procs.AddRange(Process.GetProcessesByName("excel"));

        foreach (Process p in procs)
        {
            if ((int)p.MainWindowHandle > 0)
            {
                int childWindow = 0;
                cb = new EnumChildCallback(EnumChildProc);
                EnumChildWindows((int)p.MainWindowHandle, cb, ref childWindow);

                if (childWindow > 0)
                {
                    const uint OBJID_NATIVEOM = 0xFFFFFFF0;
                    Guid IID_IDispatch = new Guid("{00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}");
                    Excel.Window window = null;
                    int res = AccessibleObjectFromWindow(childWindow, OBJID_NATIVEOM, IID_IDispatch.ToByteArray(), ref window);
                    if (res >= 0)
                    {
                        app = window.Application;
                        Console.WriteLine(app.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Потрясающе, не ожидал такого подробного ответа, спасибо!. Сам не справился с преобразованием Process в Excel.Application.